# How can we reduce the size of a image, while editing?

Tags: support, editing, images

When someone post a question with an image on it that is really huge (most of the time an iPhone screenshot), is there a way to reduce the size of the image with an edit in order to make the question more readable?

I'm referring at questions like this one: [The Storage "Used" does not add up](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229497/the-storage-used-does-not-add-up)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use img tags with a custom width attribute. In the example you linked to, I've edited it to do just that. Check the revision history to see what I've done.

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vIgO.png" width="375">
```

- iPhone 4–5s: 320
- iPhone 6–6s: 375
- iPhone 6+–6s+: 540

If you resize an image and re-upload it as a suggested edit, I'm likely to ‘reject and edit’ it and use the above instead on the original image. Resizing the image loses detail.

Feel free to use even smaller numbers for side-by-side images (e.g. 300) and add `[]()` or `[][]` link formatting around the img element to link  to the full-size image.

Comment: Nice solution, wasn't aware of that. To be fair though, detailed screenshots aren't needed usually.

Comment: @NetMage I wasn’t aware of this, what happens when you try?

Comment: @grg Sorry, I was wrong. It is just extremely restrictive in what is acceptable compared to an actual img tag (e.g. copying in the example from the Formatting help didn't work).

Answer (score 9):

*Late Note:*
This was broken for several months, but is now working again.

---

I Like grg's method, & in fact use it myself quite a lot for quick edits to posts.

There is another method, slightly more work, but this not only reduces the **apparent** size on screen, but also the **actual** image size - useful for if you're on the phone, etc.

Assuming it's your own upload, start by dragging your image into the uploader as usual, this will generate markdown like this

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]  
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEn.jpg
```

take that bottom line & duplicate it..

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]  
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEn.jpg
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEn.jpg
```

Then you make two changes...
in one link, add a character after the last existing character of the file name (not the extension)
You can use m for 'mobile' or s for 'small square'
In the other, change [1] to [2]

so

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEn.jpg
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEn.jpg
```

becomes

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEnm.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEn.jpg
```

You then change the original inline tag to reflect both versions...
    `[![enter image description here][1]][2]`
in this, the first ref [1] is the display & the second [2] is the linked image.

The result is this...

```
[![enter image description here][1]][2]  
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEnm.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEn.jpg
```

It doesn't actually matter which line becomes which option, so long as your inlined link refers to the smaller image for display & the larger for click-through.

Which then displays as this...
If you click it, it will open full size.

[image]

or alternatively as a small square...
Note I've duplicated the mobile line & added a small square as [3] so both versions refer to [2] as their full-size version.

```
[![enter image description here][3]][2]  
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEn.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/skJEns.jpg
```

Which then displays as this...  more useful for gallery views than rectangular pictures.

[image]

As pointed out by [grg](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grg) in chat, this is actually an Imgur feature rather than SE.
There are various sizing options...

s = 90×90, b/t = 160×160, m = 320×320, l = 640×640, h = 1024×1024.

Comment: seems to work for me for an image I uploaded today

Comment: @dwightk - I just re-tested on a brand new image & a couple from the past few days, in case it was taking imgur some time to background process. No joy, unfortunately.

Comment: It is working again on an edit I made today.

Comment: @NetMage - yes, it was finally fixed earlier this year - https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/327075/276027 - I keep finding the occasional post I made about it & fixing it [again]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any way to edit images within the site. What you can do though:

- Download image to your computer
- Use the editing tool of your choice to reduze the image size
- Edit the original post and replace the image with your reduced-size version

Comment: Do you think we should do a thing like that? Or after the entire work the edit get rejected?!

Comment: Same rules as always apply: Make the edit worthwhile for the time you spend on it, for the time the edit queue reviewers spend on it and the fact that it will push old posts back to the top of the page. If you just reduce picture size in a post which has bigger issues (e.g. it's not clear what the question is about at all, or there is a lot of irrelevant noise in the text, or is years old and has an accepted answer), there is a certain risk that it will get rejected.

Comment: The post linked in your question definitively falls into the "a lot of irrelevant noise in the text" category.