# Use text-align:center in inner HTML

Tags: support, images

I want to insert images to my questions and answers and, to make my post more readable, I use the HTML `img` tag.

I was looking for a way to align images at the center of the post (normally `text-align:center` in CSS).

For example, this image:

[image: options]

Is:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/t11VJ.jpg" width="250" alt="options">
```

As you can see, it's on the right side of this post. I am looking for a way to bring it to the center. How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3262/9058) on how to post images without losing the higher resolution of the original (some of your latest screenshots are hard to read).

And take a look at [Is it possible to horizontally center an image on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25835/is-it-possible-to-horizontally-center-an-image-on-stack-exchange-sites) for options on how to accomplish centered images. Or do as anybody else here does and just stop worrying about laying out your posts too much :-)